# The document has not been opened - Crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have some crystal reports on a website. They are working fine on my local machine. I'm using `Crystal Reports version 13.0.3500.0` 
The test environment it is on another server, `Windows 2008 R2`, 64 bit operating system.

The problem  is that when on the test environment I want to use a crsytal report, I get the following error: `The document has not been opened`

[image]

I spent some time already to figure it out what can be the problem, but without any success. I'm using the same `DLL-s` as in my local machine. 
I checked and the folder where I have the report has all the rights.
Can you please advise?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using IIS go to the application pool select your web site Click on Advanced Settings on the right side Set 'enable 32-bit application ' true (crystal report runtime engine for .net 32-bit had to be installed)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error before I installed Crystal Reports Runtime (21) on my server.
[Here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/) is an article where you can find download links etc.